# How to define this complicate typescript type?

Tags: typescript

```
export type Model<S> = {
  state: S,
  setState?: never,
  setStateSync?: never,
} & Record<string, any | S | ((
  this: Model<S> & {
    setState<K extends keyof S>(partialState: S | Pick<S, K> | ((prevState: Readonly<S>) => S | Pick<S, K>), callback?: () => void): void;
    setStateSync<K extends keyof S>(partialState: S | Pick<S, K>): void;
  },
  ...args: any[]
) => any)>    

export function createContext<S, M extends Model<S>>(model: M) {}
```

I want to specify a param `model` type.

`model` should be a plain object, it must have a property `state: Object`, it mustn't have property `setState` and `setStateSync`, it can have any other properties.

And if a property is a function, then the function's `this` should be `this: typeof model & { setState: XXX, setStateSync: XXXX }`...

So I declare type like above, but it not work: both `Model<S>` and `createContext` are ok, but calling `createContext` is not ok. I can not pass a param to `createContext` without error notification.

---

**Maybe code like this can show my intention more accurately:**

```
type StateAble<S> = {
    setState(
        partialState: Partial<S> | ((prevState: Readonly<S>) => Partial<S>),
        callback?: () => void
    ): void;
    setStateSync(partialState: Partial<S>): void;
}

type Model<S> = Exclude<
    { state: S } & Record<string, any> &
        Record<string, (this: Model & StateAble<S>) => any>,
    StateAble<S>
>

function createContext<S, M extends Model<S>>(model: M) { }

createContext({
    state: { a: 1 },
    abc: 123,
    def(a: number[]) {
        console.log(a.concat(1))
        console.log(this.abc)
        console.log(this.def)
        console.log(this.state.a);
    }
});
```

But typescript tells me `Type alias 'Model' circularly references itself.`

---

**Version 3:**

```
type StateAble<S> = {
  setState(
      partialState: Partial<S> | ((prevState: Readonly<S>) => Partial<S>),
      callback?: () => void
  ): void;
  setStateSync(partialState: Partial<S>): void;
}

function createContext<M extends {
  state: Object, setState?: never, setStateSync?: never
} & Record<
    Exclude<keyof M, 'state' | 'setState' | 'setStateSync'>,
    (this: M & StateAble<M['state']>) => void
>>(model: M) {

}

createContext({
  state: { logined: false },
  login() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ logined: true });
    }, 1000);
  },
  logout() {
    this.setState({ logined: false });
  },
});
```

Paste that on TypeScript-Playground and error is: `Argument of type '{ state: { logined: boolean; }; login(): void; logout(): void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ state: Object; setState?: never; setStateSync?: never; } & Record<never, (this: StateAble<any>)...'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'login' does not exist in type '{ state: Object; setState?: never; setStateSync?: never; } & Record<never, (this: StateAble<any>)...'.`.

Don't know why `Exclude<keyof M, 'state' | 'setState' | 'setStateSync'>` became `never`.

If I change `(this: M & StateAble<M['state']>) => void` to `number` and `createContext({ state: { logined: false }, a: 'some_thing' })`, then`Exclude<keyof M, 'state' | 'setState' | 'setStateSync'>` becomes correct `Record<"a", number>`.

Comment: if it's complicated that you are doing wrong coding...

Comment: What error are you getting, I can call `createContext({
    state: { boo: true },
    test(params:string) {
        console.log(this.state.boo);
    }
})`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir 
with totally the same code with the question. `createContext({ state: { boo: true }, test(params:string) { console.log(this.state.boo); } })` but `this` is `any`.
change `Record<string, any | S | ((` to `Record<string, S | ((`, then `this.state` is `{}`, I can not get `this.state.boo`